# Canvas width extends outside of page on zoom

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that I am creating via Javascript based on the size of the window with the following code:

```js
var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
    canvas = document.querySelector('#pixies'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    gradient = null,
    pixies = new Array();

function setDimensions(e) {
    WIDTH = window.innerWidth - 40;
    // For some reason above code is extending width past the window by about 40px
    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = WIDTH;
    canvas.height = HEIGHT;
}
setDimensions();
window.addEventListener('resize', setDimensions);
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
      <canvas id="pixies"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem: the canvas is being created based on `window.innerHeight` (in pixels). At 100% page view there is no problem, but at 200% a horizontal scrollbar appears and the canvas extends outwards to the right. How can I keep the canvas within the window width and prevent horizontal scroll?

Comment: body's margin. At 200% zoom it is is doubled. To avoid this, set `body{margin: 0}` in your CSS

Comment: Your suggestion didn't resolve it at all. I feel it has to have something to do with a percentage of the window's width. How can I set canvas as percentage of window?

Comment: `canvas.width = innerWidth * ( percentage / 100 )`. Could your fix you snippet so that we can reproduce your issue ? B.t.w if the problem is with the height, you'd also have to set `canvas{display: block}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for me: Set canvas styling to max-width: 100%